# Pattern recognition algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition, pattern-recognition

We are developing a software that needs to recognize shapes when the users draw it on the screen. That shapes may be circles, squares, lines, triangles, and letters like "U", "P", "D". Shapes that you can draw without lifting the finger.

We have to associate an array of points to one of that shapes, we start the research with Hough Transforms but it doesn´t work for us because we have many shapes and the algorithm varies depending on the shape.

Any ideas where we can start the research, or if there is something implemented?

Comment: I think that you would have to pay someone a decent amount of money to get this many vague and non-trivial requirements fulfilled.

Comment: I just asking for a starting point to research, a name of an algorithm, something to not have to start the development from scratch. There are a lot of applications and games that have that functionality. Thanks!

Comment: That is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't understand why. I need information about how to solve a specific problem, shapes recognition. I think that many people could have the same question because there are many apps using this feature but a few information. It's easy and is not vague if you read it with attention. I want an algorithm that solve the problem or a point of start to research, so I can make the research, solve the problem and share the answer for people who may have this question in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Reason to close as off-topic: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: This is not a specific problem. This is a whole huge range of problems. You have not presented any code with failed attempts.

Comment: We are not asking for a recommendation, we are asking for a solution to a concrete problem make a match between a sequence of points (x, y) with shapes, that is an specific problem. The code that we developed would not contribute anything to the question, would only make it less understandable. Have you got some information to share?

Comment: If it's about classification of shapes (binary-images): look up MNIST handwritten digit database including approaches. A CNN implementation done in a few hours will do that easily (did for me; if you got training-data).